# CSS - elements position when the window size changes

Tags: html, css, resize

I am looking for a pretty simple feature (i think) that somehow eludes me.

Currently on my html file resizing the window pushes the element from one side to another till a certain point. No matter how much i will narrow it the browser always try to display all the elements, even if they overlap.

let's take a simple code for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <div id=example>
            <h1>Some Heading Some Heading Some Heading Some Heading Some Heading</h1>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>

<style>
    #example{
        color:blue;
    }

</style>
```

suppose i start to make the screen smaller, narrowing it from left to right.

the "Some Heading" is pushed together with the screen and remains completely visible.
Eventually the browser breaks it to separate rows.

=====

My question is:

how can i change that behavior in a way that narrowing it from left to right
will cause some of the text to be "swollen" into the right side of the screen? (pushed beyond the borders of the window).

thanks

Comment: Give your div a fixed/min width.

Comment: are you sure? i tried it and it is still not possible to push beyond the borders. everything is always displayed.

Comment: Yep http://jsfiddle.net/vs6EE/

Comment: you're right! i misused the width property.

Comment: can i get the same behavior by using a % value in width? (suppose i want width=100% )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply give your header a static width like pixels:

```
<style>
#example{
    color:blue;
    width:200px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: thanks, but what if i want the width to be 100%? (using width in px becomes a problem, isn't it?)

Comment: Do you want the width to be 100% of the screen size? Then it'll obviously re-size itself.

Comment: Unless you mean 100% the width of the parent div, if so give the div a static width in pixels etc.. And then give the h1 tag `width:100%;`

Comment: right. on the other hand, let's say i want the headline to be on all of the width of the window when it is in full size. I can achive it by using large px value but i think that it would create differences in the display when using different browsers (unlike the 100%)

Comment: What do you mean by full size? Screens come in many different sizes these days.

Comment: for examle: i have a headline with some background. when the window is set to full size, i want the headline to be displayed all across the window. if i set the width to be 200px for examp i'll only get part of the window.

Comment: If you want the headline to fill the whole width of the window then you should set it to `width:100%`

Comment: yeah, so if i want the whole width but the behavior i get when using width in px - it can't be done?